# Ubuntu server ejecutar python script via crontab

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

Estoy tratando de correr un script en python en un server con Ubuntu pero no funciona ya probe el script manualmente y FUNCIONA correctamente pero automáticamente lo probe de 3 formas pero nada;

1) `1 * * * * /ubicacion/del/script/1.py` 
(Con permiso de ejecución y #!/usr/bin/python en el archivo)

2) `1 * * * * python /ubicacion/del/script/1.py`

3) `1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /ubicacion/del/script/1.py`

Habilite el log de cron lo "ejecuta" y no me da ningún error. Pero el archivo debe hacer un backup de imágenes y subir a otro server pero no lo hace.

Hay alguna razon para que funcione manualmente y no automáticamente?

Comment: Lo estas usando con algún entorno virtual como `virtualenv` o `pipenv`?

Comment: no utilizo entorno virtual y el script utiliza python 2.7

Comment: valida si se ejecua o no haciendo: `1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /ubicacion/del/script/1.py >> /ubicacion/del/script/ejecucion.log`

Answer (score 1):

Resolví el problema haciendo esto:

```
1 * * * * cd /ubicacion/del/script/ && /usr/bin/python 1.py
```